# Is there a way to rewrite the function data1.groupby(level=0)['total_tax'],apply(lambda x: x.shift()) to avoid Setting With Copy Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a big dataset and when I'm performing this function:

```
data1['total_t_1'] = data1.groupby(level=0)['total_tax'].apply(lambda x: x.shift())
```

I'm getting this error: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc [row_indexer, col_indexer] = value instead.

I recognize that the error is on this part: apply(lambda x: x.shift())

Can somebody would advice me what to do to avoid this issue?

Comment: The error is [probably] not because of the `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just warning you that `data1` came from a slice of another DataFrame, and that you therefore shouldn't expect the original DataFrame to be updated when you change `data1`. If you want to make the warning go away then set `data1 = data1.copy()` first. See the link from pault's comment ([How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)) for further information.